# OSX version of `mount -l`

Tags: mount

On Linux `mount -l` nicely lists all my mount points:

```
mount [-l] [-t type]
    lists all mounted filesystems (of type type). The option -l
    adds the labels in this listing. See below
```

The same command does not seem to exist on OS X... Can someone point me to the right command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Terminal type, `man mount` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

It says:

> The system maintains a list of currently mounted file systems. If no
>   arguments are given to **mount**, this list is printed.

So, in Terminal type, `mount` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: How silly of me... I was so used to the `-l` option that this default usage totally escaped me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Under OS X, the `mount` command has the `-t` option. The volume label is also shown in the output as part of the mount point. For example on my Mac, the command `mount` produces the following output.

```
/dev/disk0s5 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk0s2 on /Volumes/Shark (ntfs, local, read-only, noowners)
/dev/disk0s3 on /Volumes/Shark2 (ntfs, local, read-only, noowners)
/dev/disk0s4 on /Volumes/FREEDOS2011 (msdos, asynchronous, local, noowners)
/dev/disk0s7 on /Volumes/Steelhead2 (hfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/USB4GB (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

To get just the `ntfs` file systems, I would use the command `mount -t ntfs`. The output is shown below.

```
/dev/disk0s2 on /Volumes/Shark (ntfs, local, read-only, noowners)
/dev/disk0s3 on /Volumes/Shark2 (ntfs, local, read-only, noowners)
```

In both cases, the volume labels are displayed.

```
Identifier  Label
----------  -----------
disk0s2     Shark
disk0s3     Shark2 
disk0s4     FREEDOS2011
disk0s7     Steelhead2
disk1s1     USB4GB
```

What is missing is the label for `disk0s5` which happens to be `Steelhead`.

An alternative way to display labels is to use the command `diskutil list`. For my Mac, this output is shown below.

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Shark                   202.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Shark2                  202.0 GB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data FREEDOS2011             50.0 GB    disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Steelhead               245.1 GB   disk0s5
   6:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s6
   7:                  Apple_HFS Steelhead2              198.9 GB   disk0s7
   8:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s8
   9:                        EFI REFIND                  134.2 MB   disk0s9
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 USB4GB                  4.0 GB     disk1s1
```